# Android Equivalent to a .NET UserControl

Tags: java, android, .net, layout, user-controls

I'm just getting into Android development.  I'm trying to figure out if its possible to setup something similar to a user control that's available in Silverlight, WP7, or ASP.NET, where I can define a reusable component in a layout, and then embed that layout in another layout.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you shouldn't map things in a certain framework to others in another framework, you should learn how each platform does things in order to be able to compare them.

Comment: That's not very helpful.  It's perfectly reasonable to ask how to do something in the context of something you already know.

Comment: Aren't fragments the equivalent to UserControls?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Here is the [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).  You have a couple of different options.  I've found just building compound controls has been good enough for me, but you can do fully custom `View`s if you need to.